# Positioning buttons on video

Tags: html, css

So I try to display video on my web page, but decided to use custom style for buttons. Problem is that I can't really position them like I want. If I use css position: absolute and use margins to get them into position, it only works till I resize the window - when window gets small, mute and fullscreen button merge together. Are there any ways to keep them away from each other?

```css
#full-screen {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: 95%;
}

#mute {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div id="video_container">
    <video id="video" width="100%">
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
<!-- Video Controls -->
    <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause"><input type="image" src="buttons/play.png"></button>
    <progress id="progress" value="0" min="0">
         <span id="progress-bar"></span>
      </progress>
    <button type="button" id="mute"><input type="image" src="buttons/volumeOn.png"></button>
    <button type="button" id="full-screen"><input type="image" src="buttons/fullScreen.png"></button>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Make parent relative position, and use top/left/right/bottom on childs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to solve your problem. this code to set your button within the Video-controls div

```
#video-controls{
position:relative;
}
```